# A problem about polar coordinate of $\mathbb{R}^2-{0}$ in Bott-Tu's book.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

In the Chapter 6 of Bott-Tu's *Differential Forms in Algebraic Geometry*(P71, P72), they use the polar coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^2-{0}$ to define the global Angular form:

> Now suppose the rank of $E$ is $2$, and ${U_{\alpha}}$ is a coordinate open cover of
> M  that trivializes $E$. Since $E$ has a Riemannian structure, over each
> ${U_{\alpha}}$ we can  choose an orthonormal frame. This defines on $E^O|_{U_{\alpha}}$  polar
> coordinates $r_{\alpha}$ and  $\theta _{\alpha}$; if $\pi^*x_1,...\pi^*x_n$ are coordinates on ${U_{\alpha}}$, then
> $\pi^*x_1,...\pi^*x_n,r_{\alpha},\theta _{\alpha}$ are coordinates  on $E^O|_{U_{\alpha}}$. Here
> $E^O|_{U_{\alpha}}$ is the complement of the zero section in $E$, which is a vector bundle.

Since the angel function $\theta_{\alpha}$ is not continuous on $\mathbb{R}^2-0$, I wonder why $\pi^*x_1,...\pi^*x_n,r_{\alpha},\theta _{\alpha}$ are coordinates  on $E^O|_{U_{\alpha}}$. Do they mean that for $E^O|_{U_{\alpha}}$, we discompose it by four charts:

${U_{\alpha}}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^+,{U_{\alpha}}\times\mathbb{R}^-\times\mathbb{R},{U_{\alpha}}\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^-,{U_{\alpha}}\times\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}$, ,

and on these charts, $\theta_{\alpha}$ is smooth? If we do this, I wonder if the Euler class could be defined by Bott-Tu's way, I am not sure if I am right.

Maybe this problem is too strange, It has a simplified version；
How to understand the angel function $\theta$ in $\mathbb{R}^2-{0}$, and 1-form $d\theta$, since $\theta$ is not continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2-{0}$.

Comment: This question is essntially the same as the newer one you asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4234122/a-problem-about-polar-coordinates-of-mathbbr2): Bott and Tu is wrong in claiming that $\theta_\alpha$ is a coordinates function on $E^O|_{U_\alpha}$. But I guess they use only $d\theta$, which is well-defined.