# A problem about polar coordinates of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-forms

In Bott-Tu's book, *differential forms in Algebraic Topology*, they used the angle function $\theta$ in $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$, and its differential $d\theta$, how to understand them, since $\theta$ is not continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$.

Comment: Depends on how $\theta$ is defined.  If (for example) $\theta$ is defined so that $-\pi < \theta \leq \pi$, then $\theta$ is continuous at all points $(x,y)$ except for points $(x,0) ~: ~x \leq 0.$

Comment: I think I can understand $d\theta$ by $\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}$,However, in Bott-Tu's book, they use $x_1,..,x_n,r_{\alpha},\theta_{\alpha}$ to give a coordinate of a vector bundle $E_{\alpha}$, I can not understand this '$\theta$'